# Close app via the home button, I want it to go back a page, and refresh the page, is it possible?

Tags: android, google-maps, refresh

I'm getting a bit confused here. I've got a navigation drawer with a Fragment in it for my google maps page. The idea is they click a marker, they see a button that takes them to a new activity.

What I want is for the user to see the maps page again if they exit the app via the home button, and refresh it, when they go back into the app. So is that possible?

Calling `onStop();` in the activity does take me back to the fragment, but the map does not refresh. I call `finish();` in the `onStop();` so backstack wise the maps page is the most current.

Is there a method I'm missing that will let me refresh the map within it? I have a method that pulls the markers and what not when the map loads. But of course this just takes be back to where I was. I want to call the `refreshMap();` method.

Maybe a cheaty way. I have a refresh button in the onCreateOptionsMenu so maybe just things like onKeyDown to force a back button, maybe we can force a tap on that button? Guess that's only for hardware buttons.

Hopefully someone can guide me the right direction. The refreshing is important because otherwise the user can click on an expired marker from hours ago and still get the offer.

Thanks for any help given, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static boolean homeClick = false; 

 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
     homeClick = true;
 }
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

Check if homeClick has clicked, if so then we finish the current activity and go back to the last

Make sure the first activity (the one with the map is still active, if not make an intent before finish()

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {


    if (homeClick) {
   homeClick = false;
   finish();
 }
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: So the first bit goes in the activity, do I call it in the onStop then just before it closes? Oh hold on, they both go in the activity?

Comment: That won't let me update the map, because the call is in the maps fragment. It will let me go to the maps page. The last time I tried this it created a new instance of the map, I'll try with the Intent

Answer (score 0):

I think with the way onResume() works on the Maps page I should not refresh it. An just do a check before they go to activity, to make sure it has not expired. I should just go back to the page and tell them it has expired.

It only refreshs the map if the map is null. If I change that you will be stuck on a loop when using the app again, since onResume it called.